# How can i import thing in js ? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, import, discord.js

I got a problem with import in js for a discord bot.
This is a part of my code :

```js
import * as Discord from "discord.js";
import * as fs from "fs";

import config from "./config.json";

const client = new Discord.Client();
```

But, i got an error :

```js
import * as Discord from "discord.js";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at internal/modules/esm/translators.js:100:15
    at Object.meta.done (internal/modules/esm/create_dynamic_module.js:48:9)
    at file:///C:/Users/Teo/Desktop/altv-server/resources/discord/bot/index.js:9:13
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:111:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:131:24)
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error. Can someone help me to solve my issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `dicord.js` [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#logging-in-to-discord) since **they released their package as a common js** package in order to load it, you should **use ES5 importing style with `require`.**

So it should be like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

Comment: I have replaced all import by require, but now, I got another issue. When I'm trying to import a file, I got `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Teo\Desktop\altv-server\resources\discord\bot\dbconfig.mjs`

Comment: @Scoffgard You don't have to replace all the imports, some of them may have written in ES6, so just import `discord` like what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Require Library?

You can't selectively load only the pieces you need with require but with imports, you can selectively load only the pieces you need. That can save memory.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js/browser');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```js
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
```

source: // https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/es6-syntax.html#template-literals