# How to use 'discord.js' module in SvelteKit? "require is not defined" error occurrs

Tags: ecmascript-6, discord.js, vite, commonjs, sveltekit

I'm trying to use `discord.js` module to develop a Discord bot in SvelteKit.

In the [Discord official example](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/es6-syntax.html#template-literals), "discord.js" can be used with following code,

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
```

However, `"require is not defined"` in SvelteKit as only `import` is valid syntax with Vite.

#### Then, how can I use `discord.js` module in SvelteKit?

###### Env:

- SvelteKit (with TypeScript) version: latest version on August 23, 2022 ("svelte": "^3.44.0",)
- Default settings used (e.g. svelte.config.js, tsconfig.json)
- `discord.js` version: 14

###### What I have done:

- Change the `require` to `import` => `"Failed to fetch dynamically imported module"`
- Install `discord.js` with devDependencies
- Try using trick as shown below => `Module "module" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "module.createRequire" in client code.`

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
```

###### Similar quetions I found:

- ['require' is not defined - Sveltekit with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69369543/require-is-not-defined-sveltekit-with-typescript)
- [require is not defined](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/vc7cnw/require_is_not_defined/)
- [How can i import thing in js ? (discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61638926/how-can-i-import-thing-in-js-discord-js)

Comment: Have you [restarted the dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69300341/typeerror-failed-to-fetch-dynamically-imported-module-on-vue-vite-vanilla-set)?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the app multiple times using "npm run dev" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This probably only runs on an endpoint (i.e. on the server).
2. Make sure the `import` statement has the correct form:

   ```js
   import { REST, Routes } from 'discord.js';
   ```
3. The `vite.config.js` apparently needs to be adjusted because the package or one of its dependencies uses the `BigInt` data type which is only available in newer versions of JS:

   ```js
    const config = {
        plugins: [sveltekit()],
        build: {
            target: ['es2020'],
        },
        optimizeDeps: { esbuildOptions: { target: 'es2020' } },
    }
   ```

Comment: For your anser #1, doesn't it run as lib (e.g. src/lib/discord.ts)? If it doesn't, would you please tell me why? When I use it on lib and import it from front (i.e. svelte file), the following error ocurrs: 'Failed to resolve entry for package "https". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.'

Comment: That error there is the issue, it relies on certain native Node modules which will not be available in a browser. Maybe you can find sufficient replacements for them and can make it use those instead, but chances are that it's just not possible.