# Problem with converting code to ES6 Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, es6-modules

I have old code for discord bot and i'm trying to write this in ES6. Here is code:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commandsBackend/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commandsBackend/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

if (interaction.commandName === 'ping' || interaction.commandName === 'p') {
  client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args, db);
};
```

I have problem with this line

```
const command = require(`./commandsBackend/${file}`);
```

I tried to convert this to:

```
import command from `./commandsBackend/${file}` or import {command} from `./commandsBackend/${file}`
```

but this isn't working.
I have this error:

```
file:///home/runner/VeriusBot/index.js:33
  import command from `./commandsBackend/${file}`;
         ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I want to convert this that this will be working, i don't want to write all imports for all commands on top of file. Can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a template literal in an import statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955213/how-do-i-use-a-template-literal-in-an-import-statement)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i import thing in js ? (discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61638926/how-can-i-import-thing-in-js-discord-js).  According to discord.js [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#logging-in-to-discord) since they released their package as a common js package in order to load it, you should use ES5 importing style with require.

So it should be like this:

`const Discord = require('discord.js');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that this code should be within an `async` function, you can do:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commandsBackend/').filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'))

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = await import(`./commandsBackend/${file}`)
  client.commands.set(command.name, command)
}

if (['ping', 'p'].includes(interaction.commandName)) {
  client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args, db)
}
```

Comment: Isn't `await` needed?

Comment: @Konrad improved answer based on your comment.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Inside your package.json file, change `"type"` to: `"type": "module"`

```
{
  // ^^^
  "type": "module",
  // VVV
}
```

Comment: I have it already